# How can i add a textbox control to a workflow?

Tags: workflow

I want to create a Shopping System on a Sharepoint site. There is a Products list and My Shopping Cart list. in Products list i added a Workflow to copy a list item from product list to My Shopping Cart list. And in products list i added a Custom Action that named "Add to the basket". When the user clicks on the product name a form opens and clicks the "Add to the basket" image button. After than forms ask for the Start the Workflow or Cancel. I want, before users start the workflow, users can enter quantity info. is it possible? products and shopping cart list have 2 columns, product name and quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create initiation form values in the workflow.  Then when the workflow is executed, the user will have to supply values which can then be used in the workflow.